# WPF Window Location

Tags: wpf, window, location

I'm trying to get a Window to start in the bottom right corner of the primary display (as it will definitely be used on multi-monitor systems). So far, I've got it working, but the window first flashes somewhere in the middle of the screen for a split second, then moves to the correct location. Here's what I've got:

```
public MyWindow()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            var workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
            var corner = transform.Transform(new Point(workingArea.Right, workingArea.Bottom));

            this.Left = corner.X - this.ActualWidth;
            this.Top = corner.Y - this.ActualHeight;
        }));
    }
```

I've tried the obvious stuff like hiding the window then showing it again once the move is complete, but that doesn't seem to work either as it just then never shows the window at all.

I know its a pretty small issue, but its oddly quite an annoying and I'd love to get it sorted!

Comment: Hi, I know this might be in your mind earlier but hope this could help. You said that you have achieved this already with the use of the code posted above, Why not try to set the default visibility of the window to collapsed then set it to visible after the execution of your code.

Comment: For some reason when I did that, the window never showed up. It might have been because I had the Visibility = Visibility.Visible in the wrong place, but either way, it felt hacky :)

Comment: Yeah It felt like a little tricy :) anyway congrats for solving the problem without my dirty idea :) lolz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the window location in a Window.Loaded event handler:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (o, e) =>
        {
            var workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
            var corner = transform.Transform(new Point(workingArea.Right, workingArea.Bottom));

            this.Left = corner.X - this.ActualWidth;
            this.Top = corner.Y - this.ActualHeight;
        };
}
```