# Custom window position setting - multiple monitors - bottom right of parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with setting up a custom window in WPF - it should be a popup like info that opens up on the bottom right of the parent window.

I've tried a couple of things:

this would always show popup on the bottom right of the main display:

```
var desktopWorkingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
```

this only works well if the window is not maximized and SOMETIMES when it's maximized:

```
var parent = Application.Current.MainWindow;
this.Left = parent.ActualWidth + parent.Left - this.Width;
this.Top = parent.ActualHeight + parent.Top - this.Height;
```

However, when I move the window around (maximize etc), then my popup window will appear pretty randomly on the screen.
In winforms I used to do it as simple as

```
FileDownloadedPopup pop = new FileDownloadedPopup();
pop.SetFileInfoLabel(downloadPath);
pop.Location = new Point(form.Right - pop.Width,
form.Bottom - pop.Height);
```

What's the right approach in WPF?

---- edit

Summing up, I need to show my window on the bottom right of the parent window, regardless of parent window size, window state and whether it's on main display or secondary display.

Comment: Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063886/wpf-window-location

Comment: Hello - no, because this sets the window into bottom right of main display. I want to set it in the bottom of the parent, regardless of which display it's on (and whether its maximized or normal size)

Comment: In my honest opinion the best way to solve this is to re-template the Window to add this popup container to it and make it slide in and out when needed(using a storyboard). 

You can play around with settings the position of the child window to make it appear at the bottom right of the parent window, but there are always some edge cases and it will end up with bugs when you lease expect them.